# Bootstrap collapsed menu doesn't show styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

When I open my collapsed menu/nav on my website (the collapsed menu shows at XS and SM screen sizes), I dont receive any styling of my dropdown menu, the links just stands in a row, which ofc is a problem for me. I dont know why the styling doesn't work, and I checked that my php docs links with my bootstrap.css and, so on. I would be glad if someone could help me solve this.

The website: http://www.haagmedia.dk/klf

HTML

```
<!-- MENU/NAV MD & LG  MENU/NAV MD & LG  MENU/NAV MD & LG  MENU/NAV MD & LG -->

<div class="row hidden-xs">    

    <div class="navbar-fixed-top">   

        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">NYHEDER</a></li>
                <li><a href="holdet.php">HOLDET</a></li>
                <li><a href="kampe.php">KAMPE</a></li>
            </ul>

            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/klf_logo.png" class="logo-knap"></a>  

            <ul>
                <li><a href="support.php">SUPPORT</a></li>
                <li><a href="om-klf.php">OM KLF</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<!-- MENU/NAV XS & SM  MENU/NAV XS & SM  MENU/NAV XS & SM  MENU/NAV XS & SM -->     

<div class="visible-xs">   

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <a href="index.php"><img style="margin-right: -46px;" src="images/klf_logo1.png"></a> 

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">  
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">NYHEDER</a></li>
                <li><a href="holdet.php">HOLDET</a></li>
                <li><a href="kampe.php">KAMPE</a></li>
                <li><a href="support.php">SUPPORT</a></li>
                <li><a href="om-klf.php">OM KLF</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="kontakt.php">KONTAKT</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</div>  

<!-- MENU/NAV SLUT  MENU/NAV SLUT  MENU/NAV SLUT  MENU/NAV SLUT  MENU/NAV SLUT -->
```

CSS

```
/* MENU/NAV  MENU/NAV  MENU/NAV  MENU/NAV  MENU/NAV */
.navbar {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 91px;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow:  0px 1px 14px #A4ABB0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

.navbar ul>li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

.navbar ul>li>a {
    color: #A4ABB0;
    padding: 42px 29px 23px 29px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar .active {
    color: #208AF0; 
    border-bottom: 5px solid #208AF0;
}

.navbar ul>li>a:hover {
    color: #208AF0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #208AF0;
}

.navbar a>img {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}



/* MENU/NAV COLLAPSED   MENU/NAV COLLAPSED   MENU/NAV COLLAPSED   MENU/NAV COLLAPSED */
.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 5px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle.collapsed {
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle.collapsed .icon-bar {
    background-color: #A4ABB0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar{
    background-color:#208AF0;
}
```

Comment: The styling you have used will be used in all screen sizes and affects the menu even  below 768px. Use Media-queries to target the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the bootstrap css, which is ok, but you have to be careful with it, look at your `stylesheet.css` at line 28:

```
.navbar ul>li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

and on your line 35:

```
.navbar ul>li>a {
  color: #A4ABB0;
  padding: 42px 29px 23px 29px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

those styles are ALWAYS been applied to your `.navbar`, and because of that your "mobile navbar" (ie. XS ans SM) is having this wrong behaviour.

You can add some `media queries` to fix it, so you can apply diference style roles to your `navbar`, depending on your display size.

Some `media query` example:

```
@media(max-width: 767px){
  .navbar ul>li {
    // your css to make your collapsed menu works as you wish
    // just remove your float and it will shows as a list
    // and not in a row
  }

  .navbar ul>li a {
    // display block, small padding should works too
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 29px 5px 29px;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    // also set you ul to display block so your list be get 100% width
    display: block;
  }
}
```

you can use more than one media query, so you just need to be creative :)